# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name in EF- but in Table Attribute set proper name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, ef-fluent-api

I have created class to configure the corresponding table name in the database with proper name "MyTableInfo" by `Table` attribute:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("MyTableInfo" , Schema = "dbo")]
public class MyTableInfo
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and I use Fluent API in model class for add some constraints:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Answers>()
        .HasMany(e => e.MyTableInfo)
        .WithRequired(e => e.Answers)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.AnswersId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

But when I try get data from the table I have an exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.MyTableInfoes'

however I don't have even any string in my source files with text `MyTableInfoes` !!!

How to fix this ?

Comment: Might this have to do with some "pluralization" setting?

Comment: @Marcel - seems like this - but why "pluralization" work with DataAnnotations.Schema and don't work with Fluent API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is EF is Generating pluralize name for the tables there is an option to remove that configuration.

In your DB context class, override the following method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

to have it not pluralize the generated table names.

Comment: Of course - but my answer give others information about good practics, for example don't using 2 different methods for configure EF ...

Comment: And for example not many people know about that Data Annotations Attributes have been affected to "pluralization" setting whereas Fluent API doesn't ...

Comment: There are two different things, one is used to configure the whole context which applied in the whole context and the second one is used to configure that specific table only, for example, `one to many cascade delete convention, `Pluralizing table name convention` there are many conventions can be set on the context AND you can use fluent API for specific table.
The table attribute is used to set the name of the table but it doesn't mean that the default configuration will be over right. if you use fluent API it means you are specifically configuring that table schema information.

Answer (score 0):

Reason - using 2 different methods for configure EF - Data Annotations Attributes and Fluent API.
Just delete `Table` attribute and add the same in Fluent API:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyTableInfo>().ToTable("MyTableInfo");
```

As per the default conventions, EF creates a table name matching with  property name> + 's' (or 'es') - this is reason why I can't find string `MyTableInfoes` in my source files ...